# Best approach for converting list of nested dictionaries to a single dictionary with aggregate functions

Tags: python, pandas, list, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I've looked through a lot of solutions on this topic, but I have been unable to adapt my case to a performant one. Suppose I have a list of dictionaries stored as:

```
db_data = [
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-20T17:55:54.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c","d"],
      "key_2": ["a","b","c","d"],
      "key_3": ["a","b","c","d"]
    }
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-20T18:32:27.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c","d"],
      "key_2": ["a","b","e","f"],
      "key_3": ["a","e","f","g"]
    }
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-21T17:55:54.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c"],
      "key_2": ["a"],
      "key_3": ["a","b","c","d"]
    }
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-21T18:32:27.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c"],
      "key_2": ["b"],
      "key_3": ["a"]
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to get a data aggregation from the list output as a dictionary, with the key values of the results object as the keys of the output, and the size of the set of unique values for each date for each key.

I am attempting to aggregate the data by date value, and outputting the count of unique values for each key for each day.

Expected output is something like:

```
{
  "key_1": {
    "2020-04-20": 4,
    "2020-04-21": 3
  },
  "key_2": {
    "2020-04-20": 6,
    "2020-04-21": 2
  },
  "key_3": {
    "2020-04-20": 7,
    "2020-04-21": 4
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far is using `defaultdict` and loops to aggregate the data. This takes a very long time unfortunately:

```
from datetime import datetime

grouped_data = defaultdict(dict)

for item in db_data:
  group = item['start_time'].strftime('%-b %-d, %Y')
  for k, v in item['results'].items():
    if group not in grouped_data[k].keys():
      grouped_data[k][group] = []
    grouped_data[k][group] = list(set(v + grouped_data[k][group]))
for k, v in grouped_data.items():
  grouped_data[k] = {x:len(y) for x, y in v.items()}

print(grouped_data)
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. I have read that `pandas` might help here, but I am not quite sure how to adapt this use case.

**Edit**
I am not sure why this was closed so fast. I am just looking for some advice on how to increase performance. I would appreciate if this could get re-opened.

Comment: will you explain your input transition to output?

Comment: Just updated the description but I will include it here: I am attempting to aggregate the data by date value, and outputting the count of unique values for each key for each day.

Comment: Hey why was this closed? How can I be more focused here? I am looking for some advice on how to increase performance. @sahasrara62

Comment: sorry if it causes you little inconvenience, reopened the problem for you

Comment: if not getting solution here you can ask them in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, I will try there!

Comment: Alright @JasperSardonicus, I adjusted my answer.. I think you might like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below has a generator assigned to `flat_list` that flattens the original dictionary out into a list of tuples. Then the defaultdict is set up to be a dictionary with two levels of key, `key` and `date`, for which the value is a `set`. The set is updated for each key/date so it contains a list of unique items. This is vaguely similar to the example code, but it should be more efficient.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from functools import partial
>>>
>>> flat_list = ((key, db_item['start_time'][:10], results)
...               for db_item in db_data
...               for key, results in db_item['results'].items())
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, set))
>>> 
>>> for key, date, li in flat_list:
...     d[key][date].update(li)
...
```

Testing it out, we get the same number of list items per key/date as the counts in the example:

```
defaultdict(..., {'key_1': defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {
                           '2020-04-20': {'a', 'd', 'b', 'c'}, 
                           '2020-04-21': {'a', 'b', 'c'}}), 
                  'key_2': defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {
                           '2020-04-20': {'a', 'f', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e'}, 
                           '2020-04-21': {'a', 'b'}}), 
                  'key_3': defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {
                           '2020-04-20': {'a', 'f', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'g', 'e'}, 
                           '2020-04-21': {'a', 'd', 'b', 'c'}})})
```

If you prefer the value to be a count of list items, you can just do `len(d[key][date])`.

Since `flat_list` is a generator, it doesn't do all its looping separately, but does it in conjunction with the loop that builds the dictionary. So in that way it's efficient.

[Update] I'm not seeing the performance gain on my system with CPython 3.8 indicated in the comments. The algorithm here is only marginally faster than the example in the question after fixing the line with `item['start_time'].strftime('%-b %-d, %Y')` to `item['start_time'][:10]`.

With that said, efficiency is addressed by taking advantage of the `set`. Operations on a set are very fast, and we're just updating its elements. We don't need to test a list for group membership first. Checking lists for membership is a very slow operation that can really add up in loops. The time-complexity for checking a list for membership is O(n) per item added, whereas set operations are O(1) per item added.

Reference on time complexity of python data types and operations: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: so this is close, but it does not take into consideration the need for uniqueness in the results

Comment: Oh.. so the lists under keys need to be counted as unique items..

Comment: exactly. The expected output above is what I am looking to achieve :)

Comment: WOW! I can't like this enough! I implemented this for my real data set and for a list of just ~400 items, the performance went from ~50 seconds to ~2 seconds. You are a godsend, @Todd!